# Django Rest Framework Get Forms as json

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Django Rest Framework is populating the HTML form.[Like This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByFWSiIw10_kNmtqNnJmQndvaHc/view?usp=sharing)

Is any way possible can get the html form in json format as well along with default behaviour.  In case of this attached image something like

```
{
    "first_name": {"type":"text"},
    "last_name": {"type":"text"}
}
```

Comment: I am using OPTIONS method of the API url.

Comment: Cool Thanks It worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

As Umut suggested in comment, using OPTIONS, just like POST, GET PUT etc. It worked.